# How is decoherence due to the environment compatible with the Copenhagen interpretation?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, wavefunction-collapse, decoherence

Let's say that "decoherence" is that transition from a pure quantum state to a mixed state due to interactions with the environment. (A reasonable definition?)

How is that compatible with the Copenhagen interpretation of quantum mechanics -- specifically with the role of the observer?

By the above definition, observation is an example of decoherence; the observer in the Copemhagen interpertation is part of the environment and causes the wavefunction to collapse. However, decoherence can also happen by (often-unwanted) coupling of the quantum system to a heat bath. Does that mean that the heat bath is an "observer"? If not, what causes the apparent** wave function collapse when there is no human observer?

Having worked with crummy superconducting qubits, I'm aware that they can decohere very quickly and apparently without human observation. E.g. suppose I initialize a qubit in a pure state. If I measure it after 10 ns, the qubit still appears to be in a pure state. If I measure the qubit after 1ms, it appears to have decohered into a mixed state. (I could determine that by trying to perform some quantum operation on the qubit.) Since I did not measure or interfere with the qubit in the intervening time, it does not seem that I could have caused the decoherence ("collapse").

** I'm using the word "apparent" to [mean](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/apparent#Adjective) "Appearing to the eye or mind (distinguished from, but not necessarily opposed to, true or real); seeming."

Comment: The "collapse" bit is when the observation picks out a *single* component of the mixed state. This is not the same as a pure state superposition decohering into a mixture.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the importance of the difference between the two? IIRC, a system in a "mixture" is (or can be) in _one_ eigenstate of the hamiltonian; you just don't know which one state it is until you look. So in both cases, a superposition of states is reduced to a single state. The difference I see is that in one case you observe the system soon after it turns into one state but in the other case you wait a little while.

Comment: @Inmaurer - If you're talking about a mixed state generated by taking the reduced density matrix of a subsystem A of a larger pure state, I think it's potentially misleading to say that A "is" in one of the states, since the full state is the pure state of the whole system. I think it would be better to say the probability distribution for measurements of a subsystem A of a pure state is mathematically identical to the probability distribution you'd get for a distinct system A' that *wasn't* part of a larger entangled state, and which was in a mixed state that happened to match the reduced

Comment: (continued) density matrix for A. Then you are free to assume that A' is definitely in one of the pure states that are part of its mixed state, and you just don't happen to know which one, but it's not so obvious that you can say the same for A.

Comment: mixed states are NOT decohered states, they are states where the phases of the wavefunctions are well defined, just not in an eigenstate that will give a unique eigen value at measurement. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_state

Comment: @anna v - Whose comments are you addressing? If mine, I didn't say that mixed states "are" decohered states, just that the reduced density matrix for a subsystem of a larger entangled state (like a subsystem that's become entangled with its environment in Zeh's approach to modeling decoherence) is a mixed state. If someone else, I don't see where Inmauerer or Mark Mitchinson said all mixed states are decohered states either.

Comment: @Hypnosifl I was addressing the question. I then went along and answered it

Comment: @annav, Maybe I used "mixed state" in the wrong way. The article you linked to notes that "a mixed quantum state is a statistical ensemble of pure states". If I initialize a qubit once and let it decohere, I do not have an ensemble of anything because I only have one sample; I just have a qubit that's in one eigenstate or the other because of decoherence. That's what I'm looking to understand, because "collapse" also leads to the qubit being in one eigenstate or the other.

Comment: The two definitions overlap for small numbers, because a density matrix can be defined for your qubit and the incoming photon that decohered it, it is a different language useful for large numbers where randomness and averages enter.

Comment: @annav, thanks for clearing that up; that makes sense.

Comment: The so-called Copenhagen interpretation isn't even self consistent. If I were you I wouldn't worry about reconciling anything against it. Also, sorry to hear about the crummy qubits. May your $T_2$'s increase in future years.

Answer (score 2):

> Let's say that "decoherence" is that transition from a pure quantum state to a mixed state due to interactions with the environment. (A reasonable definition?)

Mixed states are NOT decohered states, [they are states](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_state) where the phases of the wavefunctions are well defined, just not in an eigenstate that will give a unique eigen value at measurement.

> How is that compatible with the Copenhagen interpretation of quantum mechanics -- specifically with the role of the observer?

In the quantum regime "observation" is interchangeable with "interaction", it is not necessary to have a human observer. An electron scattering off an atom "observes" the atom.

> By the above definition, observation is an example of decoherence; the observer in the Copemhagen interpertation is part of the environment and causes the wavefunction to collapse.

The "collapse" language is a fancy way of saying that an instance was picked from a probability distribution, which is what the state function gives us where composed of pure states or mixed. The square of the state function gives us a probability distribution and an observation gives an instance in that distribution. It is as ridiculous as saying that when getting a five in a throw of the dice, the probability distribution of the dice throws has collapsed.

> However, decoherence can also happen by (often-unwanted) coupling of the quantum system to a heat bath.

Now yes, a heat bath leads to decoherence. The easiest way to think of coherence and decoherence is in the [density matrix formalism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Density_matrix).

> A density matrix is a matrix that describes a quantum system in a mixed state, a statistical ensemble of several quantum states. This should be contrasted with a single state vector that describes a quantum system in a pure state.

A density matrix has rows and columns of all the pure state functions comprising an ensemble of paticles. Off diagonal elements carry the phase information between two pure wave functions.

[image: expect with densitymatrix]

In theory, the whole universe could be described by one density matrix. h_bar though being a very small number and the macroscopic dimensions of a heat bath together with the enormous number of particles ( 10^23 per mole) reduce the density matrix to its diagonal elements. That is when a system of particles is decohered, when the phase information is lost.

> Does that mean that the heat bath is an "observer"? If not, what causes the apparent** wave function collapse when there is no human observer?

The multitude of interactions in a heat bath and the macroscopic dimensions ensure decoherence, the loss of phases between state functions because they cannot be measured.

> Having worked with crummy superconducting qubits, I'm aware that they can decohere very quickly and apparently without human observation. E.g. suppose I initialize a qubit in a pure state. If I measure it after 10 ns, the qubit still appears to be in a pure state. If I measure the qubit after 1ms, it appears to have decohered into a mixed state.

a mixed state is not decohered. still there exists a density matrix with non zero off diagonal elements

> (I could determine that by trying to perform some quantum operation on the qubit.) Since I did not measure or interfere with the qubit in the intervening time, it does not seem that I could have caused the decoherence ("collapse").

All matter emits black body radiation according to the temperature, i.e. photons impinged on your qubit. Obviously some of them interacted and changed the state function describing the setup. On a large scale this is the heat bath.

Comment: "Mixed states are NOT decohered states, they are states where the phases of the wavefunctions are well defined, just not in an eigenstate that will give a unique eigen value at measurement" But there are also pure states that are not eigenstates--and if you decompose a pure state into a superposition of eigenstates, doesn't each of the eigenstates get assigned a "well-defined" phase? If so this isn't a good *definition* of "mixed state". I had thought the basic definition was just a statistical mixture of pure states, where each pure state can be assigned some classical probability.

Comment: Yes, I'm also confused by your definition of a mixed state. Can you reconcile your definition with the one you linked to: "A mixed quantum state is a statistical ensemble of pure states".

Comment: "In the quantum regime 'observation' is interchangeable with 'interaction'". That basically answers my question. However, is your answer answer widely accepted? For example von Neumann (who came up with the density matrix formalism), does not appear to believe what you said. It looks like he believed that consciousness was required for observation: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann%E2%80%93Wigner_interpretation Also, is your answer compatible with the Copenhagen interpertation? (You never explicitly answered that.)

Comment: "a mixed state is not decohered. still there exists a density matrix with non zero off diagonal elements" Why does it have to have non-zero off diagonal elements? (Heat baths have all non-diagonal elements as zero, right?) If there are non-diagonal elements after a qubit decoheres, how would I show that?

Comment: @Inmaurer  If you look at the construct of the density matrix you see that each psi is projected to all other psis. If there is no "angular" (phase) information this projection is zero. Subsets along the diagonal can exist in large statistical samples but eventually because of the great number of interactions and the smallness of h_bar they go to 0 . You already said that you found your qubit in a mixed state, I have no knowledge on qubits so cannot know how you did it. Decoherence means that the correlations between the state functions are lost and one has the trace, each psi with itself.

Comment: @Hypnosifl I have given a link for mixed and also for the density matrix, which is a statistical mixture of psi functions describing the components.  A randomness enters in the definition which creates actually the decoherence, imo.

Comment: @Inmaurer consciousness is metaphysics , and generally all the navel gazing over interpretations touches on metaphysics. I am an experimentalist and what I know are "measurements" and quantum mechanical models that fit the measurements very well. When I measure the crossection of proton proton scattering I do it though innumerable proxies,tracks, detectors, programs... the last my eyes and brain. The original "collapse" is a proton hitting a proton, and interaction.

Comment: @annav, I agree that we're getting into philosophy here, but that's ultimately what I'm asking. Many introductory quantum mechanics books talk about the Copenhagen interpretation in simple terms ("observers", "observations", "measurements", etc.) without explaining what they are -- leading to the impression that human intervention is necessary. I like equating interaction with observation, but it leaves some things unanswered. E.g. two qubits can interact and remain in a superposition, so is that interaction not an observation? Anyhow, thank you for your answers.

Comment: @annav If interaction is the same as measurement, then why is collapse a separate dynamic in a multi-particle system from the dynamics described by the Schrodinger equation ? What about interaction-free measurement?

Comment: @JohnDavis There cannot be measurement without some interaction . How can there be a record? There are interactions never recorded by a human , but mathematics allows us to extrapolate , using them as probes. Collapse is a term that describes an instance ( a measurement) that will build up  the probabilistic distribution predicted by the solutions of S equation for the specific boundary conditions

Comment: @annav interaction-free measurement is an important if not-so-well-known feature of QM. See: http://scitation.aip.org/content/aapt/journal/ajp/49/10/10.1119/1.12592. Also interaction does not necessarily cause collapse so measurement and interaction are far from synonymous in QM. Collapse is a separate, but almost certainly related dynamic to decoherence.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't studied this in any detail, so take what I say with a grain of salt. But from summaries I've read, like the [essays on decoherence.de](http://www.decoherence.de/), I think that in the Copenhagen interpretation "collapse" would still have to be understood as conceptually distinct from decoherence. I think a way to see this would be by imagining an idealized Schroedinger's-cat type situation where a complex system could be kept entirely isolated from the external universe by some sort of perfect "box" (like an ideal square well with infinite potential barriers on each side), up until the moment when we on the outside choose to "look in the box" and measure what's inside. Then you can divide the system *within* the box into a combination of some small subsystem A + everything else, which is treated as the "environment" for the subsystem. In this case, even *before* we look inside and collapse the wavefunction, there can still be decoherence between the subsystem A and its environment within the box, but until the act of measurement, the entire system within the box must be modeled by us as being in a single pure state. In this case the effects of decoherence on probabilities would become apparent if we imagined "opening" the box and measuring only the state of subsystem A, which in the Copenhagen interpretation would be the first point at which any real "collapse" of the wavefunction occurs. From summaries I've read, measuring only one subsystem of a larger entangled system requires generating a "reduced density matrix" for subsystem A from the larger pure state of the entire system, and it is with this step that subsystem A is modeled as being in a mixed state. So the idea is that if there has been interactions leading to decoherence between subsystem A and its environment in the box before our opening the box and collapsing the wavefunction, the probabilities of different measurement results for A will look different than if there had *not* been decoherence between A and its environment prior to measurement (and there can also be degrees of decoherence rather than it being an all-or-nothing affair, from what I understand).

Along these lines, the essay ["How decoherence can solve the measurement problem"](http://www.decoherence.de/essays.html#zeh) by [H. Dieter Zeh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H._Dieter_Zeh) (one of the founders of the current understanding of decoherence) on the site I linked to above says:

> As an application, consider the particle track arising in a Wilson or
>   bubble chamber, described by a succession of collapse events. All the
>   little droplets (or bubbles in a bubble chamber) can be interpreted as
>   macroscopic "pointers" (or documents). They can themselves be observed
>   without being changed by means of "ideal measurements". In unitary
>   description, the state of the apparently observed "particle" (its wave
>   function) becomes entangled with all these pointer states in a way
>   that describes a superposition of *many* different tracks, each one
>   consisting of a number of droplets at correlated positions. ...
>   Decoherence leads to the same *local* density matrix (for the combined
>   system of droplets and "particle", which therefore seems to represent
>   an ensemble of tracks. The correlations between the wave functions of
>   different droplets as forming tracks were already known to Mott in the
>   early days of quantum mechanics, but he did not yet take into account
>   the subsequent and unavoidable process of decoherence of the droplet
>   positions by their environment. Mott did not see the need to solve any
>   measurement problem, as he had accepted the probability interpretation
>   in terms of classical variables. In a global unitary quantum
>   description, however, there is still just *one global superposition*
>   of all "potential" tracks consisting of droplets, entangled with the
>   particle wave function and the environment: a universal Schrödinger
>   cat. Since one does *not* obtain an ensemble of potential states
>   without a collapse, one cannot select one of its members by a mere
>   increase of information.

For another possible example, in the experiment described [here](https://www.uni-due.de/~hp0198/research/decoherence/collisionaldeco/index.html) involving fullerene molecules being sent through a number of slits in a gas-filled environment, if we were to model the whole system as being isolated until the a position measurement of the fullerene after it has passed through the slits, I expect that--just as was found experimentally--we would predict different degrees of interference fringes in the spatial pattern of the fullerenes depending on the pressure of the gas, which affects the degree of decoherence that occurred when the fullerene was passing through the slits. With sufficient decoherence, I think the spatial distribution of the fullerenes upon the position measurements would be the same to the distribution we *would* have seen if we had simply placed detectors at each slit (and perhaps at points throughout the space between the slits), and modeled each detection-event as a collapse. If that's right, then in this sense decoherence would seem to mimic the effects of prior collapses, although in the Copenhagen interpretation you would still need to assume a final collapse after the fullerene had passed through all the slits in order to talk about a final probability distribution for the fullerene's position. But if the statistics for subsystem A in the ending measurement can be identical for the two cases "a number of individual collapse-inducing measurements during the time-span of the experiment, then an ending measurement" and "decoherence without collapse during the time-span of the experiment, then an ending measurement", that might be taken as a sort of intuitive reason to support interpretations in which *all* apparent collapse is really just a simplified way of modeling the effects of decoherence.

Comment: Why is your answer so long and so complicated? To the first question of Inmaurer you could have answered by "yes, correct". About the observer, human observer has no role, i.e. both decoherence and collapse (two DIFFERENT things) don't need a human, or a human apparatus, to be there and become aware of the result.

Comment: (continuation) Decoherence is caused by lack of isolation of the system from its environment, (which indeed can be a bath). It transforms a pure state to a mixture. The collapse selects from the mixture ONE component, that all. If the wave function occupies some volume, an absorbing block over part of this volume, already collapses the wave-function on the rest of the volume, without our apparatuses being there.

Comment: Sofia - If by "first question" you meant the parenthetical "(A reasonable definition?)", I guess it didn't really register, but I would say that if you model the subsystem and environment as a single quantum system as Zeh suggested, then decoherence only causes the subsystem's reduced density matrix to become a mixed state, while the state of the subsystem + environment is still modeled as a single pure state. And I'm not sure why you're making the point about "human observer" to me, I didn't say the final measurement which we model as a "collapse" needed to be done by a human.

Comment: can we let Zeh aside? I read what Zeh said and what many, many others said (and none of them solved the problem - with some people I had exchange of letters, but when asked precise questions they ran from corner to corner - I prefer not to give names). Now, can you tell me simply which one is the SYSTEM and which one is the ENVIRONMENT? Do you still refer to Schrodinger's cat? This example was proposed just to exemplify that a macroscopic body cannot be in a quantum superposition of states. But for our talk it is not a good case to examine - too complicated.

Comment: @Sofia - I would have thought that all derivations of equations relating to decoherence ultimately start from a model similar to Zeh's, where you model both the system you're interested in and its environment (the division presumably being a matter of choice, depending only on what element's behavior you want to predict measurement outcomes for) as a single entangled system evolving according to the Schroedinger equation, and then show that after decohering interactions, the equations predict the reduced density matrix for the system will have greatly reduced off-diagonal terms.

Comment: (continued) Is that wrong, is it possible to *derive* equations relating to decoherence from more basic QM premises without first treating the system and environment as a single entangled system and then looking at the reduced density matrix for the system?

Comment: (continuation) Your statement "subsystem + environment is still modeled as a single pure state", can't be correct. Putting in simple words, FORGET ABOUT! Let me say why! The environment is an OPEN system, it is the room, and the room is not isolated from the building, etc., etc., so which pure state? The environment is so loosely defined.

Comment: @Sofia - But I'm asking about how you derive the equations theoretically. The basic postulates of QM don't include anything about "open systems", they only allow you to mathematically model the behavior of self-contained systems, isn't that true? (assuming equations relating to decoherence are assumed to be derived, not basic axioms of QM)

Comment: I apologize, this utility is unstable, I am trying to answer and it jumps to other screens. I am still with your question that begins by (continued). So, you ask "is it possible to derive equations relating to decoherence from more basic QM premises without first treating the system and environment as a single entangled system and then looking at the reduced density matrix for the system?" You see, you cannot regard system + environment as a single entangles system. As I said, the environment is hard to define. In simple words, you can't even say how many particles (e.g. photons it contains.)

Comment: (continuation) What I know is that for a system in contact with a bath, there is plenty of articles in th arXiv quant-ph. Basically, the equations show how each "mode" of movement (state) of the studied subsystem, varies in time due to the contact with the same, and with the other, modes in the bath. But I repeat, the subsystem and the environment CANNOT BE in a PURE STATE, simply because you don't know how many particles contains the environment. A basic quantum law leading to decoherence is the FLUCTUATION AND DISSIPATION law.

Comment: @Sofia - But I'm talking about a theoretical derivation, which doesn't require that you "know" the exact details of any real-world environment, just a generic hypothetical state similar in broad terms to real ones. Don't they model the environment using quantum laws, perhaps with quantum statistical mechanics so they don't have to worry about the precise state? Or are you saying that equations relating to QM can be derived treating the environment as wholly classical from the start? How could that be, when the basic assumptions of QM don't give any rules for quantum/classical interactions?

Comment: No, I don't say that the environment is treated as classical, but as a system with extremely many degrees of freedom, and over these degrees of freedom one has to take average. But, there is a good couple of years since I followed the course in quantum optics where I learnt of the "fluctuation-dissipation law". Can't we continue tomorrow? (By the way, this law is also I Wikipedia, but it is about classical particles, so it's not what we talk here.) I will look in my database, there is plenty of articles about decoherence there.

Comment: @Sofia - Averaging over many degrees of freedom sounds like some form of quantum statistical mechanics--and aren't all such statistical analyses justified by deducing out what the average behavior would be for a large ensemble of pure states? If so, the fact that you don't explicitly model these pure states individually wouldn't change the fact that the logic of the derivation is to figure out what would happen in an ensemble of cases where the system + environment are treated as self-contained and in a pure state. And sure, we can continue tomorrow.

Comment: I found an article on decoherence, I hope that would please you, and I find it quite correct. Here is the reference: A. Cuccoli, P. Liuzzo-Scorpo, and P. Verrucchi, "Getting information via a quantum measurement: the role of decoherence", in the arXiv quant-ph, index 1411.2797. To put it in short, it begins by considering the subsystem to be examined + the environment in a pure state, but that, when the environment is doesn't have a big number of components. When this number increases, they explain that its density matrix becomes diagonal. But, you'll see more details in the article itself.

Comment: @Sofia - Thanks. So would you agree that the logic of the argument is based on supposing a composite state consisting of environment $\Xi$ + subsystem $\Gamma$, with this composite in a pure state, and deducing how the density matrix for the the subsystem should be expected to change (specifically the suppression of off-diagonal elements) due to entanglement with that environment, even if approximations/large-scale limits are used for the environment without explicitly calculating its quantum state in precise detail?

Comment: Can any of the downvoters explain what they think is wrong in my answer? Sofia made some arguments but I addressed them, and as I said in my last comment, the last paper posted by Sofia quite clearly matches my understanding since it's based on treating the environment and subsystem as being components of a single quantum state, and then looking at how the density matrix for the subsystem will evolve according to the usual quantum evolution equations.

Comment: I will gladly look at your problem tomorrow. Can you wait? What shall I say, I disagree with Anna. Sometimes I have the feeling that people give points according to what they like or dislike, without being able to discern between what is correct and what isn't. I also have a lot of such problems. But, can we talk tomorrow? By the way what is the time in your country now? In my country is after midnight.

Comment: @Sofia - Thanks, when you get a chance please look at the paper by Cuccoli et al. and see if you think it contradicts my basic summary of how decoherence is derived. I'm on the east coast of the U.S., right now it's 6:22 pm here.

Comment: No, I won't have the time to look at papers. I can tell you what I see in your answer, and maybe you would change that. The fellow is confused on two issues: the difference between decoherence and collapse, and the role of a human observer in collapse. I fully subscribe to your statement "in the Copenhagen interpretation "collapse" would still have to be understood as conceptually distinct from decoherence". But your example that follows is very complicated, including a system and a subsystem. For a confused person is difficult. I also got lost. Use simple examples.

Comment: If you want, I can help you to change the answer to a more concise and clearer one. I think that you can simply delete this present answer, and post an improved one. So, I would do. We all learn, we are given the right to delete an answer and post another that we think as better. About Anna's answer, I disagree, despite my big appreciation for her knowledge.

Comment: @Sofia - The paper I was talking about was the one you had referred me to in a comment, and you yourself had mentioned that "it begins by considering the subsystem to be examined + the environment in a pure state"--so I do think this is the standard way of analyzing decoherence, and if so I don't want to change my answer to remove the explanation about treating the subsystem and environment as a single pure state, applying the quantum evolution equations, and seeing what happens to the density matrix of the subsystem.

Comment: (continued) If you think I am confused about decoherence and collapse, please specify which parts of my answer suggest this to you (as well as which parts suggested to you that I was confused about 'the role of human observer in collapse'--though in this case I'm pretty sure you're misreading me, since I never said anything about human observers and don't think collapse needs to be due to human observation in the Copenhagen interpretation).

Comment: (continued) But if you don't think anything in my answer is incorrect on a technical level, I would prefer to leave it as is rather than change the focus significantly--I mainly just wanted to ask the downvoters if they thought there was anything *incorrect* about my answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19763/discussion-between-sofia-and-hypnosifl).